# Add array object to minimongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I have a chat app, that is using `Ionic 2` and `Meteor` with `MongoDB`.  It works perfectly.

However, everything is stored in the `MongoDB` on the server, so each time a user wants to view their messages, they need to be connected to the `Meteor/Mongo` Server running in the cloud. Also, if one user deletes their `chat`, it will delete the `chat` on the `MongoDB`, and the corresponding other user will also have their `chat` deleted.

I would like similar functionality as *WhatsApp* where the `messages` are held locally on the device (I am using `SQLite`), and only new `messages` are held in the cloud until both users download them.

Currently my app iterates over a `Mongo.Cursor<Chat>` object. It also observes this object (`this.chats.observe({changed: (newChat, oldChat) => this.disposeChat(oldChat), removed: (chat) => this.disposeChat(chat)});`).

I get `chat` data from `SQLlite` that I have stored locally (`Array<Chat>`).

**Question**

Is it possible to add the `SQLite` data (`Array<Chat>`) to the `Mongo.Cursor<Chat>`? When I do so, I want to just add to `minimongo` and not `MongoDB` on the server.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Asp per advise below, I do the following:

```
let promise: Promise<Mongo.Cursor<Chat>> = new Promise<Mongo.Cursor<Chat>>(resolve => {
  this.subscribe('chats', this.senderId, registeredIds, () => {
    let chats: Mongo.Cursor<Chat> = Chats.find(
      { memberIds: { $in: registeredIds } },
      {
        sort: { lastMessageCreatedAt: -1 },
        transform: this.transformChat.bind(this),
        fields: { memberIds: 1, lastMessageCreatedAt: 1 }
      }
    );

    this.localChatCollection = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
    console.log(this.localChatCollection);

    chats.forEach(function (chat: Chat) {
      console.log('findChats(): add chat to collection: ' + chat);
      this.localChatCollection.insert(chat);
    });
```

Will update if it works.

**UPDATE**

When I do the following, it `inserts` the `chat` object:

```
      let promise: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = this.findChats();
      promise.then((data: Mongo.Collection<Chat>) => {

        let localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
        data.find().forEach(function (chat: Chat) {
          console.log('==> ' + chat);
          localChatCollection.insert(chat);
        });
```

However, if I define the `localChatCollection` globally, it does not `insert` the `chat` object. There are no errors but the process just stops on the `insert` line.

```
private localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
....
         this.localChatCollection.insert(chat);
```

Any ideas how I can get this to insert into a globally defined `collection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add the SQLite data (Array) to the Mongo.Cursor? When I do so, I want to just add to minimongo and not MongoDB on the server.

Meteor itself knows nothing about SQLite, but it sounds like you have that part of it working.

To just add to minimongo and not the mongodb server, you're looking for a client-side collection. Just pass `null` in as the first parameter to the call to create your collection i.e.

```
var localChatCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null)
```

You can then insert to `localChatCollection` the same way you would with a synchronized collection.

[Source: Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection)

Comment: Hi cobberboy, thanks for the feedback.  I am not using a `Mongo.Collection`, but rather a `Mongo.Cursor`.  I am using `observe` on the `Cursor`. Is it possibel to do the same with a `Collection`?

Comment: According to the docs, I am unable to `observe` the `Collection`. So I don't think the above is a suitable answer, unless I'm wrong?